# A better way to select from multiple rows of the same column in a joined table

Tags: mysql

My query is currently working, it just seems to me there is an easier/better way to get the same result. But my knowlegde is limited to basic SELECT,UPDATE,INSERT and DELETE queries with the occasional LEFT JOIN (as I understand the basics for linking the other table and fetching the data from that 2nd/3th/.. table.)
It is for a PHP page that will list machines, I'm trying to use 1 prepared query to generate all the info I need for the list and avoid queries within the loop if results.

For the question I'll limit it to just the involved data.
There are multiple languages, English as main/default, each machine can have up to 4 tags with some specifications.
The 3 tables involved are:

1. the machine_list, containing the machine_id and some basic info that isn't language specific, also not relevant for now.
2. the specification_list, containging specification_id,machine_id, lang, specification_value. specification_id links to the specification table with the name of the specification in all the used languages e.g. width, model, number of gears etc. (not relevant for this case), machine_id to link to the machine, lang to link to the language. and spefication_value holds the value of the specification e.g. 300mm,T1000,4 gears etc. Some specifications are translated, but some values would be the same for all.
3. the machine_tags with tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4,machine_id. tag1-4 can hold the specification_id or 0 if not linked.

For my list I want to show the general info + up to 4 tags, if the tags are available in the language, show it in that language. And the tags are to be shown in the order set.

This is my current query:

```
SELECT m.machine_id, t1.spec_value,t2.spec_value,t3.spec_value,t4.spec_value,t1e.spec_value,t2e.spec_value,t3e.spec_value,t4e.spec_value
  FROM machine_list as m
  LEFT JOIN machine_tags as t ON m.machine_id=t.machine_id
  LEFT JOIN machine_specifications as t1 ON m.machine_id=t1.machine_id AND t.tag1=t1.spec_id AND t1.lang = ?
  LEFT JOIN machine_specifications as t2 ON m.machine_id=t2.machine_id AND t.tag2=t2.spec_id AND t2.lang = ?
  LEFT JOIN machine_specifications as t3 ON m.machine_id=t3.machine_id AND t.tag3=t3.spec_id AND t3.lang = ?
  LEFT JOIN machine_specifications as t4 ON m.machine_id=t4.machine_id AND t.tag4=t4.spec_id AND t4.lang = ?
  LEFT JOIN machine_specifications as t1e ON m.machine_id=t1e.machine_id AND t.tag1=t1e.spec_id AND t1e.lang = 'en'
  LEFT JOIN machine_specifications as t2e ON m.machine_id=t2e.machine_id AND t.tag2=t2e.spec_id AND t2e.lang = 'en'
  LEFT JOIN machine_specifications as t3e ON m.machine_id=t3e.machine_id AND t.tag3=t3e.spec_id AND t3e.lang = 'en'
  LEFT JOIN machine_specifications as t4e ON m.machine_id=t4e.machine_id AND t.tag4=t4e.spec_id AND t4e.lang = 'en'
  WHERE m.active = 1 ORDER BY m.list_date DESC
```

This is used in a prepared statement, loop the fetch and show the list. using the php code to show the tag if linked and show the text in the right language if the text is available.

As said, it works but I feel there might be a better way, it feels wrong to add 2 alias of the same table for each value I need. And for example I know that I now fetch 4 columns that we are not going to use, but I lack the knowledge to filter this out on the SQL side -> or if that is even a good idea. I expect around 300 active machines max, maybe in a couple of years the total list would be 1000+, I don't know if this has effect on possible solutions (with performance impact in mind)
Also with possible changes in the future in mind, like what if instead of 4 we want to show 5 tags. In it's current form I need to add 2 more aliasses to the query.

The current machine_tags table might not be a good fit for this, I can imagine a different setup with machine_id, specification_id, order and then have a max of 4 rows per machine could work as well. But I don't see (as in lack of knowledge) a lot of change in how I would fetch the specification values, I think I might need more joins for the 4 rows instead of the 1 for 4 columns.

Here is a sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86a824/1
In there i've added the query that would go on the dutch language (nl) and added aliasses to the selected values (In the prepared php statement I bind them to variables so for me they were already different)

Comment: Incidentally, a result set comprising myriad identically named keys doesn't  seem very useful!

Comment: @Strawberry Thank you, had to find out how that worked, but think i managed. As for the identically named keys, I'm binding the results to variables in php with the prepared statments so for me they are already different.

Comment: I can't imagine how that works, but ok

Comment: @Strawberry I hope I understood you correctly, you were pointing at the ' t1.spec_value,t2.spec_value,t3.spec_value,... etc' all selecting spec_value?

Comment: Yes. But it sounds like you've got it figured out.

Comment: @Strawberry Yeah, I edited it for the example in the sqlfiddle. For me, when I run the query in the prepared statement of php it binds it to the variables with $stmt->bind_result($machine_id,$tag1_lang,$tag2_lang,...etc); But I see your point.